# Azure devops kill processes run by a task on cancellation

Tags: azure-devops

I have a build pipeline which runs some automated tests using the nunit.exe runner.
e.g.

```
  - powershell: ./nunit.exe etc etc...
```

If my build pipeline is cancelled, I want to kill the Nunit process started in that task (these are currently not being killed straight away and consequently causing the pipeline to fail when it is re-run as the test files cannot be deleted).
To kill the Nunit processes when the pipeline is cancelled I have some thing like this:

```
  - task: MyCleanUpTask
    condition: canceled()
```

It looks like I should then be able to use something like powershells taskkill to kill the Nunit processes as the next step in this task.
However, rather than using something like

```
TASKKILL /F /IM nunit.exe
```

to kill all Nunit executables running on the VM, can I be explicit and just kill the processes started in the above task? e.g. Can I store the process ID's for this task and kill those processes later on if the pipeline gets cancelled? Or is there another way to do this?

Comment: Why don't you spin up a new vm per run? This way they don't affect each other.

Comment: I don't have control over this - my team are assigned 1 vm and 2 build agents on that vm.

Comment: Can you wipe the vm at the start of each run, and if you've got custom tools that needs to be installed, then create a new image with them in. This way it gurantees that you have a clean run.

Answer (score 0):

There is no such an Id or something else for us to specify a process. A task may open more than one processes, but it only point out the target .exe and the .dll. So, you have no way to specify a certain process and kill it.

I think you can start a new vm to separate it.

Answer (score 0):

Add a "**Process.Clean**" variable in the pipeline definition and set it to "**true**" should help.

Answer (score 0):

One way would be - assuming that not 2 pipeline invocations start at nearly same time - to fetch the running NUnit Processes with their PIDs. This would become your exclusion list, as they are not spawned by your pipe invocation.

When starting your NUnit TestRunner, fetch the list again - every new NUnit / PID not on the exclusion list would be assumed as spawned by your task, and should be assured to have properly closed on the end of the pipeline invocation or be manually killed by using their PID(s).

Another, less error-prone approach: Start the TestRunner process with some (more or less) unique argument. Then query the TestRunners processes and those with the command line arguments containing the set argument are those you have to clean. I'll use a similar approach during long running webdriver tests with high parallelity (sometimes 60 long running webdriver sessions on a single desktop). With the pipelines, you have a top candidate to use: Use the buildId.

To query the command arguments, you must actually use the Common Information Model (CIM) or the more or less superseeded Windows Management Interface (WMI) - with  current powershell versions, you should really use CIM - while older versions might force you to fall back to WMI. Here are examples for both:

**CIM Variant**

```
$process = "nunit.exe"
Get-CimInstance Win32_Process -Filter "name = '$process'" | select CommandLine
```

**WMI Variant**

```
$process = "nunit.exe"
Get-WmiObject Win32_Process -Filter "name = '$process'" | Select-Object CommandLine
```

I dont accurately remember if nunit.exe itself does spawn child processes. If it does, you should - before killing - check for processes having one or multiple of your identified processes as parent process. This way you can traverse a potentially existing tree of processes and really ensure everything gets properly cleaned.